# Whats the best way of defending in the post?

Tags: nba2k12

While the offensive post game has been updated in 2k12, the defense still remains the same with the standard clutch, steal, and block key strokes.  What is the best way to defend down in the post?  Just use the standard clutch defense and try to block if possible (hoping that you weren't pump faked) or should I avoid jumping and going for the block completely and focus on the steal?

Also, whats the best way to defend the turnaround fadeaway jumper in the post?

Should I call for a double team?

Comment: Are you concerned about fadeaways from an opponent in the post, or just fadeaways in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not go for the steal. Stay on the ground.**

Going for the block or the steal will ruin you. You best bet is to stay on your feet. The standard movement of the man on offense is to fade if he is backing in to a man.

Also, the best way to stop a fadeaway *is* jumping.

So don't jump until he fades, then go for the block.